# Personal field in registration form joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, field

I have added a field call ID, but I need that this fields has this mask #-####-#### how can I do that in order to see for example 1-7878-7878

How can I do that ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You cant able to create file with the name of `ID`. because in `Joomla` registration the table already have `ID`. So you have to define new field name.

```
`field_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default ''
```

You have to declare the field type as `varchar`.

Hope this will helps you...